# Css not rendering the properties correctly after the script call has been made

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius: 7px; to make my accordions and buttons curvy.And its working fine for now.There was a point in my application where my accordion need to change the colour when we click it.Both the accordions were using two different images.And for that i have written a javascript function to perform the operation

```
$('.accordion').live("click", function() {
        $(this).next('.content-toggle').toggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('section-closed')){
            $(this).addClass('section-open');
            $(this).removeClass('section-closed');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('section-closed');
            $(this).removeClass('section-open');
        }

        var total = $('.accordion').length;
        var open = 0;

        for (i=0; i<total; i++) {
            if($('.faq-accordion').eq(i).hasClass('section-open')){
                open = open + 1;
            }
        }

        if (total != open) {
            $('.show-all').show();
            $('.hide-all').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.hide-all').show();
            $('.show-all').hide();
        }
    })
```

and i am using css to get the colour and other attributes.This is working in a great way in Fire fox but in IE7 and 8 the the accordion is unable to render the css.Its able to render the accordions with all the attributes including the curvy-corners.But,its remaining the same,When i click them.I am able to sense the change in the bar as the text in the accordion is changing,But the accordion that need to change in to different image when clicked (i.e) 'section-open' to 'section-closed' and 'section-closed' to 'section-open' is not changing.Its working fine when i remove the -webkit-border-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius: 7px;But my main idea is to make them curvy.seems like a IE bug is there any other alternative cause the css should perform the same way after the script call has been made.

Comment: Post the CSS block as well please for both .section-open and .section-closed

Comment: Border Radius is not supported in IE7-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border Radius is not supported in IE7-8.  Thats why removing it has fixed your problem.  You did say, however

> Both the accordions were using two different images

So what you could do is put the "curvy corners" on your images instead. Those will show up just as good in IE7 and 8

Comment: :is there any way that if there is no image and we are using attributes like back ground color,width and padding and the curvy corners to make a accordion bar and with a rounded corners on it.your solution was working perfectly for the images but in our current requirement,we dont want to use a image for any accordions.so the problems back again,as stated once again i am unable to render the css for the bar where it need to change the colour.Is there any solution for this tricky one.Thanks

Comment: The easiest and most consistent way to do this in all browsers is to use images.  So if you don't have one, make one.  IE7-8 will never support border radius.

Comment: i am using curvycorners.js for IE any ways,and unfortunately we were not allowed to use the images any more.Any ways thank you very much for your reply mikey.

Answer (score 1):

The important issue is that `border-radius` is not supported in IE7-8 so that is why it does not show..

---

On another note, though, you can improve your code a lot by caching references to jQuery result sets..

```
$('.accordion').live("click", function() {
    var self = $(this); // caching $(this) since it is being used a lot
    self.next('.content-toggle').toggle();
    if ( self.hasClass('section-closed') ){
        self.addClass('section-open');
        self.removeClass('section-closed');
    }
    else
    {
        self.addClass('section-closed');
        self.removeClass('section-open');
    }

    var total = $('.accordion').length;
    var open = 0;
    var faq = $('.faq-accordion'); // caching $('.faq-accordion') since it is being used in a loop 
    for (i=0; i<total; i++) {
        if( faq.eq(i).hasClass('section-open') ){
            open = open + 1;
        }
    }

    if (total != open) {
        $('.show-all').show();
        $('.hide-all').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.hide-all').show();
        $('.show-all').hide();
    }
});
```

even better the

```
    var open = 0;
    var faq = $('.faq-accordion'); // caching $('.faq-accordion') since it is being used in a loop 
    for (i=0; i<total; i++) {
        if( faq.eq(i).hasClass('section-open') ){
            open = open + 1;
        }
    }
```

could become

```
var open = $('.faq-accordion:has(.section-open)').length;
```

Comment: @petrioli:Thanks for the reply.